# Subtract column position using Macros using StarBasic in LibreCalc given a range of columns eg. A1:B1 - must result 1

Tags: range, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

Subtract column position using VBA (libre StarBasic) macro in LibreCalc given a range of columns eg. A1:B1  must result 1

I have a set of ranges
I would like to get the Column position difference as integer using VBA macro in Libre Calc
eg.

> B17:C28,E17:G28,L17:O28
>
> It must results (C-B) = 1, G-E = 2,  O - L = 3

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use "Columns.Count" for  ActiveSheet.getCellRangeByName("a1:a1") to get the information of subtracting column position in a Range.

```
Dim sDataRng 'Where is the data


' Constant with ranges
Const SCells = "B1:C1,E1:G1,L1:1"

' split constant using as separator ",".
aCells = Split(SCells,",")
 

Sub subtract_column_position 

for i  = 0 to 2 step 1  
            
        ActiveSheet = ThisComponent.CurrentController.ActiveSheet
        sDataRng    = aCells(i)
        oRange      = ActiveSheet.getCellRangeByName(aCells(i))

        print oRange.Columns.Count - 1

next i 

end sub
```